# Trying to Set Up SSH Tunneling To MySQL Server for MySQL Query Browser

Tags: ssh, mysql, putty, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to set up SSH tunneling on a remote web server to another MySQL server so that the database can be browsed easily with MySQL Query Browser. I'm following this page but cannot connect to the MySQL server. http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/access-your-mysql-server-remotely-over-ssh/

What I've done:

1. logged in to the web server with Putty via SSH.
2. typed `ssh -L 33060:[database]:3306 [myusername]@[webserver_address]` where [...]s are altered by the actual information.
3. I was asked a password and typed it and got the following message. So it seems login was successful.

   > socket: Protocol not supported
   >
   > Last login: .... 2012 from ....
   >   Copyright (c) 1980, 1983, 1986, 1988, 1990, 1991, 1993, 1994
   >          The Regents of the University of California.  All rights reserved.
   >
   > FreeBSD 7.1-RELEASE....
   >
   > Welcome to FreeBSD!
4. Opened MySQL Query Browser in Windows and entered

`Server Host:` localhost
`Port:` 33060
`UserName:` *myusername*
`PassWord:` *mypassword*

And it says,

```
Could not connect to the specified instance.
MySQL Error Number 2003
Can't connect to MySQL Server on 'localhost' (10061)
```

Sorry if this is too basic. Thanks for your information.

Comment: Why are you creating the tunnel on the web server?  Shouldn't you be setting up the tunnel in putty?  Doesn't your web server already have access?  I am having problems following what you are trying to do here.  Do you want to access the mysql server from your Windows client where you are running putty?  Or what?

Comment: @Zoredache `Do you want to access the mysql server from your Windows client where you are running putty?` -- Yes, exactly. I'd like to browse the remote database with a nice GUI implemented software from my PC. I'm just following the instruction of the link I posted. If this could be set up all in Putty, I'd like to do it in Putty. That way I don't have to log in to phpMyAdmin via the web browser, which is somewhat slow and cumbersome compared to direct access with a such method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to access a remote system from your windows host which you are using Putty from, you need to be creating the tunnel within Putty, not on the remote system.

Setting up a tunnel in Putty is pretty straight forward.

- Open putty
- Load your save session if you have one, or enter any connection information.
- Scroll down to the Connection -> SSH -> Tunnels
- Set the source port to `33060`
- Set the destination to be the IP of the database server followed by `:3306` for the mysql port.  So something like `192.168.1.1:3306`.
- Click 'Add'
- Click back over to the session tab, and choose save, or simply click open to start the connection

[image: putty tunnel page]

Once connected, fire up your database application and from the application try to connect to a server listening on `127.0.0.1:33060`.

Comment: Wao, it worked! I could not find which option to choose from Local, Remote, or Dynamic and when I chose Local it went though.　Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Just saw that you're using a wrong connection string:

```
ssh -L 33060:[database]:3306 [myusername]@[webserver_address
```

Try with:

```
ssh -4 -L 33060:localhost:3306 [myusername]@[webserver_address
```

*The -4 option forces the use of IPv4 and the localhost is the destination for the bind port (in your case MUST be locahost)*

Connect using localhost:33060 and remote credentials.

### That should work!

Otherwise check your server ssh daemon configuration for this:

```
AllowTcpForwarding yes
```

Otherwise connect to your server with the `ssh -vv user@host` option ,this will bring you some more info, if you see that the bind port failed at least you should see the reason.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I get the same message when trying to connect with MySQL Query Browser. I must be doing something wrong. `AllowTcpForwarding yes` gives `"AllowTcpForwarding command not found"` `ssh -vv user@host` gives a long list of debug lines. Should I post them? One thing I'd like to be clear is that the database server and the web server have different domains in my case. So I'm afraid that `localhost` in `ssh -4 -L 33060:localhost:3306 [myusername]@[webserver_address]` does not point to the database server. I'm not sure.

Comment: I also tried `ssh -4 -L 33060:[web_server_address]:3306 [myusername]@[database_server_address]` but this gives a timeout message.

Comment: Is your PC running windows?

Comment: Yes. I used Putty to log in the web server and typed those commands in Putty.

Comment: NONOONOONONONO! Don't use this on th server, instead go in putty options, connections->ssh->options and set the correct option in port forwarding. check http://www.cs.uu.nl/technical/services/ssh/putty/puttyfw.html

Comment: Oh really. I didn't know that I wasn't supposed to do these on the server. Thanks for the link.